# Drupal 7 Pages Keep loading

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm having a problem with a Drupal 7 install where pages keep loading.

The page will load and then repeat itself over and over until Chrome suggests killing the page.

It seems to happen at random times and there are no JS errors being reported or errors retrieving the page.

Anyone else had similar issues?

Modules include:

- Panels
- Views
- Ctools
- etc

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by url aliases and/or url redirects doing some sort of circular definition. I've also seen this caused by login tobogin module setting up a circular redirect with something in the url redirect module. Find out which page is doing it and check your alieses and redirects for circular definition. It will probably be tricky to catch as it is usually two steps a -> b then b-> a, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not using the login tobogin module.